# Attiny85 water plant with mini water pump

Tags: relay, c, fluid-pump, attiny85

I`m new to electrical engineering, so it's probably a newbie problem.

I'm using a wall power supply(5V-2A) to power the [DC Motor](http://www.dx.com/p/hsyy01-water-pump-motor-w-hose-white-silver-236808#.VqvzTfkrKHs) and the Attiny85.

A C1 470uF to make the power more stable. I don't know if it is necessary, but it helped.

A D1 green led to show if it's on.

A reset button connected to ground to reset(Duh).

One relay(833H-1C-C) connected to the digital pin 0 of the attiny to turn the motor on and off.

Two rotational potentiometer connected to two analog pins(2,3) to decide how much time the mini water pump will be on(0-1023 to 1s-30s) and the other to compare to the humidity sensor to decide how dry the soil will need to be to turn on the motor.

And one [humidity sensor](http://www.dx.com/p/soil-humidity-moisture-detection-sensor-module-blue-black-white-200142#.VqwBW_krKHs).

```
#include "kPot.h" // my library, just analogReads

#define HUMIDITY_PIN 1 //humidity sensor
#define LEVEL_PIN 3 //rotational potentiometer
#define TIMER_PIN 2 //rotational potentiometer
#define MOTOR_PIN 0 //connected to the relay switch

kPot humiditySensor = kPot(HUMIDITY_PIN, 10); //(pin, average of 10 reads)
kPot levelPot = kPot(LEVEL_PIN, 10);
kPot timerPot = kPot(TIMER_PIN, 10);

int humidity = 0;
int level = 0;
int timer = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);  

  humidity = humiditySensor.Read();
  level = levelPot.Read();
  timer = timerPot.Read();
}

void loop() {
  humidity = humiditySensor.Read();
  level = levelPot.Read();

  timer = timerPot.Read();
  timer = map(timer, 0, 1023, 1000, 30000); //1s to 30s


  if(humidity < level){
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_PIN, HIGH);
    delay(timer);
    digitalWrite(MOTOR_PIN, LOW);
  }

  delay(300000); // 5min Update
}
```

[image]

The problem: The mini water pump turns on and won't stop.
I removed the reset button to make sure that wasn't resetting, didn't help.
Maybe the motor is taking too much current and reseting the attiny?
I probably have to put a diode somewhere, but as I said, I'm a newbie, so...

thanks.

Comment: Where is the decoupling capacitor? And why is there a resistor on the supply line?

Comment: Is your reset switch designed exactly as drawn? If so you probably need either an internal or external pull-up resistor to keep that input from floating when the reset button isn't pressed.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB pull-*up* is correct. A pull-down would hold it permanently in reset whether the button is pressed or not.

Comment: Lose the resistor. Don't try to drive the relay directly from your Attiny - use a transistor. Put a diode across the relay coil.

Comment: @DigitalNinja Yes, it worked, and the problem occur even without that the button, but I'll put a pull-up resistor. Thanks.

Comment: 20ohms is far too small for your LEDs series resistor. You should use one 10 to 20 times higher than that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The decoupling capacitor that you said, should be a capacitor close to the VCC and Ground of the attiny85?

Comment: @KaiqueGomes: With a very low ESR, yes.

Comment: Why do you have a 20Ohm resistor in series with the ATTiny VCC rail? You will need a 100nF or so decoupling capacitor between the VCC and GND as close as possible to the ATTiny supply pins. 470uF is not a decoupling capacitor, it's a smoothing capacitor.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I removed the resistor, I thought that was necessary to not damage the attiny and I'm changing to 100nF capacitor, thanks.

Comment: You should keep the existing capacitor as well. So have the 470uF one near the motor/relay, and add a ~100nF one near the ATTiny.

Comment: TFM usually has suggestions for which cap values that are best to use on the various pins. Also, unless the MCU has built-in pull resistor on the reset pin, this circuit is never going to work. Add external pull-up if needed. Also add a RC filter after the switch, otherwise your MCU will reset over and over upon signal bounces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not sure this will fix everything, but it should at *least* improve several problems (and avoid some component damage).

Try adding 2 diodes, a transistor, and a decoupling capacitor to your circuit like this:
[image]

EDIT: Updated schematic to include decoupling cap.

Comment: I'm adding right now the Diodes and transistor. But the decoupling capacitor was already there...C1 on the original schematic.

Comment: ok, but it needs to be on the **other** side of R2 from your orig. schematic (i.e. attached to the same end of R2 as your ttiny)

Comment: It's working perfectly with the adding of a transistor, diodes, capacitor in this schematic and the pull up resistor on the reset button. Thanks!

Comment: @KaiqueGomes: C1 is bulk, not decoupling. They serve different purposes.